# Why are the contents of my array different inside a foreach loop?

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following code That takes an array of data and consolidates the items down based on if they are related. THe first part of my code runs and returns what I expect. However after this process I need to sort the array based on the dates of the items inside it. When I go to reference this array again and try to sort the items, the items int he array change depending on whether or nor I am inside another foreach loop.

```
    foreach ($consolidated as &$item) {
        $date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($item['date']));
        $now = date('Y-m-d');

        if($date < $now && count($item['repeat_dates'])){
            foreach ($item['repeat_dates'] as $date) {
                $repeatDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date));
                if($repeat_dates <= $now){
                    $item['date'] = $repeatDate;
                    break;
                }
            }
        };
    };

    //die(json_encode($consolidated));

    foreach ($consolidated as $item){
        //die(json_encode($consolidated )); 
    };
    return $consolidated;
```

If I uncomment the first die, the code will return the following.

```
[  
   {  
      id:"3",
      date:"2018-01-25",
      last_date:"2018-01-25",
      start:"16:45:41",
      end:"17:05:41",
      timezone:"Mountain Standard Time",
      created_date:"2017-12-23 23:57:11",
      enabled:"1",
      repeat_dates:[...]
   },
   {  
      id:"15",
      date:"2018-02-07",
      last_date:"2018-04-11",
      start:"12:25:18",
      end:"12:30:18",
      timezone:"Mountain Standard Time",
      created_date:"2018-01-19 19:50:51",
      enabled:"1",
      repeat_dates:[...]
   },
   {  
      id:"16",
      date:"2018-01-24",
      last_date:"2018-02-02",
      start:"17:30:24",
      end:"17:55:24",
      timezone:"Mountain Standard Time",
      created_date:"2018-01-19 19:54:48",
      enabled:"1",
      repeat_dates:[...]
   }
]
```

However if I uncomment the second die I get the following response:

```
[  
   {  
      id:"3",
      date:"2018-01-25",
      last_date:"2018-01-25",
      start:"16:45:41",
      end:"17:05:41",
      timezone:"Mountain Standard Time",
      created_date:"2017-12-23 23:57:11",
      enabled:"1",
      repeat_dates:[...]
   },
   {  
      id:"15",
      date:"2018-02-07",
      last_date:"2018-04-11",
      start:"12:25:18",
      end:"12:30:18",
      timezone:"Mountain Standard Time",
      created_date:"2018-01-19 19:50:51",
      enabled:"1",
      repeat_dates:[...]
   },
   {  
      id:"3",
      date:"2018-01-25",
      last_date:"2018-01-25",
      start:"16:45:41",
      end:"17:05:41",
      timezone:"Mountain Standard Time",
      created_date:"2017-12-23 23:57:11",
      enabled:"1",
      repeat_dates:[...]
   }
]
```

You'll notice that an ID is repeated twice here instead of having all three ID's. I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around why this is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so when you use &$item it will be referenced to the array $consolidated for each iteration, but after the first loop is done $item still points to the last item in the array.

and then when the second for loop starts, $item will set to the first item in the $consolidated, but there is still a reference points to $item from the last loop. Since it is a reference , it will change to whatever $item is points to now.So the value of last item now changes to first item. this happens at every foreach iteration.

I would avoid using reference this way, but if you have to.

please remove the reference  using unset between loop

```
  unset($item);
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be a reference issue. If you unset $item it will clear the reference to the original $item, which remains despite starting a new foreach.

```
unset($item);
```

Comment: The horrors of using a reference in a foreach! Good call. Although you should elaborate *where* to use the unset ;)